# How to make a value appear based on 2 variables

Tags: google-sheets

I've been having touble trying to calculate a price that is defined by 2 variables. e.g. "Variable 1 is the brand of chocolate bar" and "variable 2 is the type of chocolate bar" and the value is the profit on each bar.

There are many brands and many types of chocolate bar making lots of different combinations of choclate bars and types and each combination has a different profit associated with it.

I want to profit to calculate automatically in the "profit" column

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15kPMtE6AdHuwHv9YJessAMTSCUGSreJd-z1S3jGtaa4/edit?usp=sharing

You can take a look at it here. It's the yellow column I want to use the formula for.

Comment: Profit is fixed for each conbination of the 2 variables. You can see the values for each combination of the 2 values in the spreadsheet thanks :).

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please include all relevant information in your question post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(A15&" "&B15& "*",E:E,1,0),"\d+.?\d*€")
```